# Adding jQuery UI selectmenu() to Drupal form

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a styling to the select form elements in my Drupal form using jQuery UI. I'm using Drupal 7 so the usual way to add jQuery UI would be something like this:

```
 drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.accordion');
 drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery("#accordion").accordion();});', 'inline');
```

However, when I try to add an effect that isn't bundled with Drupal 7 core, like [this one](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/), that approach doesn't work. Has anyone come across this problem before, and if so, is there a "standard" Drupal way of solving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the 'Drupal' way would be to implement [`hook_library()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_library_alter/7) to add the new element to the system:

```
function MYMODULE_library() {
  $libraries['ui.selectmenu'] = array(
    'title' => 'jQuery UI: Selectmenu', 
    'website' => 'http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/', 
    'version' => '1.8.7', 
    'js' => array(
      drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMODULE') . '/jquery.ui.selectmenu.min.js' => array(),
    ), 
    'dependencies' => array(
      array('system', 'ui.widget')
    ),
  );

  return $libraries;
}
```

And then add it to your pages using `drupal_add_library()`:

```
drupal_add_library('MYMODULE', 'ui.selectmenu');
```

Doing it this way ensures that all the necessary core UI files are included in the page automatically, and allows you to add the widget with a single line of code any time you want to.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Clive. I did that - but also added the css file in hook_library as `'css' => array(
      drupal_get_path('module', 'planb') . '/css/jquery.ui.selectmenu.css' => array(),
    ),`. I then called the line: `$('select').selectmenu();` from one of the scripts that runs on that page. However, I can see no change in the select boxes. The library has definitely been added, as confirmed by a call to `drupal_get_library`, however I must still be doing something wrong.

Comment: Is your code wrapped in a `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: Ah. Yep, that did it. Should've thought of that earlier! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to download the .js file and put it on your server. Then reference it this way:

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'YOUR_THEME_NAME'). '/js/jquery.ui.selectmenu.js');
```

Don't use drupal_add_library

Comment: Hi there Brian. Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately that didn't work - I tried adding the CSS file also to no avail. Thanks for the reply though! I'll keep searching and trying.

Comment: You added it to the right place (your js directory in your themes directory) and changed 'YOUR_THEME_NAME' to your actual theme name correct?

If you view source is the select menu js file being loaded? Are there errors in your console?